# How to stack elements from array excluding a single index

Tags: python, numpy

I got a 5x10x100 array and want to exclude one index and stack the rest, resulting in a 40x100 array.

```
old_arr.shape
>> (5, 10, 100)
```

I tried the following single line Generator:

```
i_to_exclude = 4
new_arr = np.array([element for i, element in enumerate(old_arr) if i != i_to_exclude])
new_arr.shape
>> (4, 10, 100)
```

I'm not sure how to use the Generator to stack the lists instead of appending them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np.vstack(np.delete(old_arr, i_to_exclude , axis = 0))
```

**example**:

```
old_arr = np.arange(16).reshape((4,2,2))
#array([[[ 0,  1],
#        [ 2,  3]],
#       [[ 4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7]],
#       [[ 8,  9],
#        [10, 11]],
#       [[12, 13],
#        [14, 15]]])

i_to_exclude = 3
new_arr = np.vstack(np.delete(old_arr, i_to_exclude , axis = 0))
#array([[ 0,  1],
#       [ 2,  3],
#       [ 4,  5],
#       [ 6,  7],
#       [ 8,  9],
#       [10, 11]])
```

This will also be faster than using a for-loop.